# Page repair ideas

Tags: adhesives

[image]

As pictured below, what are some ways to repair the damage shown on a book’s page?

My thought is to use several matte-finish shipping labels as a medium for fixing the page. Would this approach work? Are there others I should consider?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. It isn't clear from the picture and description exactly what the nature of the damage is or what you're trying to accomplish. It looks like an area of the paper has an irregular surface and missing text. But the image could reflect paper that was swelled by liquid and the text cleaned or abraded, or the surface was pealed away taking text with it and content from the other side of the sheet or next page is slightly showing through the thin paper remaining. What is the actual nature of the damage? What is the desired repair & how would shipping labels accomplish that?

Comment: (cont'd) Are you trying to restore the missing text?  Just reinforce the damaged paper?

Comment: A glued glass fell on it and I removed it without much care.

Comment: I would like to repair the damage. I have a copy of the text that should be in it. I believe a shipping label, with the right sized font printed on it could be a fix, albeit, not a great one.

Comment: Is there material missing or material added? I guess that there is some glue added, but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If there is material added to the surface of the page, I would try the following.

With a cotton swab I would try to remove as much of the material as possible - using some solvents, obviously. The most obvious are water and acetone. Test the process on the white space between the lines. If it works, try above some letters. Be prepared (especially in the case of acetone) that it will dissolve the letters - which you do not want.

At the end, you might want to use a black fine-tipped pen(cil) to redraw the letters - to bring the page as close to the original look as possible.

---

If material is missing, just use the last step above - the one with the pencil.

---

If you are more technically inclined, you can try to re-write the same test in your preferred text editor - using the same fonts, size, letters' position etc. Print the text - you may need to do several steps, until you get it right. When it is right, your printed paper should look like it was cut from the book.

Once satisfied with the quality of the copy, just cut / crop the printed paper and glue the paper fragments to the book page - fitting / aligning the fragment "perfectly" with the original text.

---

> A glued glass fell on it and I removed it without much care.

If you know the exact glue, then you might be able to find the right solvent for the cured glue - and use it as explained above.